# Require efficient and probably one to two liner solution to replace space

Tags: linux, bash

Having following bash scripts to find index of the command from command list

```
 #!/bin/bash
cmdlist="cmd1,cmd2,cmd,cmd24,cmd25,cmd4,cmd10,cmd9,cmd000001,cmdxyz"
cmdlist="${cmdlist//,/ }" #To Replace , with space in array list    
cmdlist="${cmdlist//cmd/ }" #To get index of command

echo $cmdlist //Added for clarification

for  a in $cmdlist
do  
    if [[ $a == *[^[:digit:]]* ]] || [[ $a -gt 50 ]] 
    then
        printf "invalid command index : %s\n" $a
    else
        printf "command index : %s\n" $a
    fi
done
```

As you can see how I extract command index from command list but it's failing (of course it fails) in some condition. So  want make some validations as follows:

1) In list, if argument is `cmd` then it will skipped and not replace space instead `cmd` string  because argument length must be greater then 3.

2) In list, if argument is `cmd0001` then also skipped and not replace space instead `cmd` string because argument length must be less or equal 5 and greater then 3.

Following above validation I achieved by taking `for..loop`, taking temporary array then compare each argument and validate then store in temporary array and finally copy temporary array in original one.So this is too long procedure.

Any one have idea for batter solution?

Like

`cmdlist="${cmdlist//cmd/ }" #To get index of command`

command only replace space instead `cmd` in target argument if condition `[[ length -gt 3 ]] && [[ length -le 5 ]]` match.

Note: have already have solution using `for..loop`.

**UPDATE:** Added more detail for what i want

I got output this from script

```
command index : 1
command index : 2
command index : 24
command index : 25
command index : 4
command index : 10
command index : 9
command index : 000001
invalid command index : xyz
```

but i want this

```
command index : 1
command index : 2
invalid command index : cmd
command index : 24
command index : 25
command index : 4
command index : 10
command index : 9
command index : cmd000001
invalid command index : cmdxyz
```

So basically leave the argument which not in validation range and mark as invalid index(nothing to do not require to replace space in place of `cmd` string.)

**More UPDATE:** Again added more detail to clarify exactly what i want

Have added one `echo` statement before `for..loop` in my script ( see modified above script ) which give me output like this

```
1 2 24 25 4 10 9 000001 xyz
```

but i want

```
1 2 cmd 24 25 4 10 9 cmd000001 cmdxyz
```

means leave argument as it is if it violate validation like in my list third argument is `cmd`.It violate the condition becasue it's length not greater then `3`.Now see last two argument in list `cmd000001,cmdxyz` It violate the condition because it's length greater then `5`. Valid argument is one for which length must be greater then `3` `&&` less or equal `5`.

Hope this will clarify what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing as per your update:

Get the values in an array and check within the loop if those meet the required criteria:

```
cmdlist="cmd1,cmd2,cmd,cmd24,cmd25,cmd4,cmd10,cmd9,cmd000001,cmdxyz"
IFS=, read -a arr <<< "$cmdlist"

for a in "${arr[@]}"
do
    v="${a/cmd/}"
    if ((v > 50)) || ((v <= 0))
    then
        printf "invalid command index : %s\n" $a
    else
        printf "command index : %s\n" $v
    fi
done
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
command index : 1
command index : 2
invalid command index : cmd
command index : 24
command index : 25
command index : 4
command index : 10
command index : 9
command index : 000001
invalid command index : cmdxyz
```

---

Old answer:

Instead of attempting to replace `,` with spaces and so on, read the string delimited by comma into an array.  Manipulate the array to get one containing the desired strings.

```
$ IFS=, read -a arr <<< "$cmdlist"
$ foo=(${arr[@]/cmd/})
$ for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i; done
1
2
24
25
4
10
9
000001
xyz
$
```

Checking...

```
for a in "${foo[@]}"
do  
    if [[ $a == *[^[:digit:]]* ]] || [[ $a -gt 50 ]] 
    then
        printf "invalid command index : %s\n" $a
    else
        printf "command index : %s\n" $a
    fi
done
```

produces:

```
command index : 1
command index : 2
command index : 24
command index : 25
command index : 4
command index : 10
command index : 9
command index : 000001
invalid command index : xyz
```

---

A note of caution:  Numbers with leading zeros (as you have in your example) would be considered as octal and might produce *unexpected* results:

```
$ [[ 0024 -gt 22 ]] && echo greater || echo smaller
smaller
```

Comment: +1, note though that you can force base10 in `bash` by prefixing the number with `10#`: `[[ 10#0024 -gt 22 ]] && echo greater || echo smaller
greater
` => `greater`. Also, single-bracket notation does not interpret as octal either: `[ 0024 -gt 22 ] && echo greater || echo smaller
greater
` => `greater`.

Comment: might be you not understand me correctly. please see my edited question. what you try i got exactly but it violate validation.

Comment: `command index : 000001` in your output? and also not just `print` purpose but `cmdlist` also modified actually.

Comment: @Jayesh I don't understand the question well enough given the edits.  I'd guess that this would give you enough to make minor modifications to suit your requirements.

Comment: @devnull Thank you for try...and sorry from me to not you clarify my question yet,let me edit the question again.sure it will redirect you.